# how show a dialogfragment from adapter without dralogfragment instance?

Tags: android, android-studio, fragment, adapter, dialogfragment

I need show a dialogfragment to press a button on a item from the adapter, and now i make this:

Adapter.class

```
public class AdaptadorEncuesta extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdaptadorEncuesta.ViewHolder> {

   public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
   View.OnClickListener {

    DialogoGrafica dialogoGrafica = DialogoGrafica.newInstance();      
    dialogoGrafica.show(((Activity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager());

   }

}

///DialogFragmen.class
public class DialogoGrafica extends DialogFragment {

    public static DialogoGrafica newInstance() {
        return new DialogoGrafica();
    }

}
```

The problem is here:

> dialogoGrafica.show(((Activity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager());

in the adapter when call `.show()`

what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to say to the DialogoGrafica What fragment you want to be shown. Something like this:

```
((Activity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Your Fragment Name")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using a listener

add this interface to your adapter`AdaptadorEncuesta`

```
public interface OnClickedListener {
    public void onItemClicked();
}
```

and then adapter constructor should look like this

```
OnClickedListener mListener;
public AdaptadorEncuesta(OnClickedListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
```

in the activity when you initialise the adapter

```
AdaptadorEncuesta adapter = new AdaptadorEncuesta(this)
```

pass `this` and implements the interface in you activity

then when you press or call on click in the adapter you will call the method `onClick()` and inside the `OnClick()` you will call the listener like that to run the `onItemClicked()` method in the activity

```
mListener.onItemClicked();
```

then method `onItemClicked()` on your activity will run that you have been do implements for his interface

now still to show the dialog inside the method

```
@Override
public void onItemClicked(View view) {
dialogoGrafica.show(((Activity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didnt told the problem, but I suppose it is no method found exception for getSupport...

The method is for the AppCompatActivity not the Activity.

So replace to:

```
((AppCompatActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager()
```

Comment: @Maniraj if you not using AppCompatActivity you should do ```((Activity)mContext).getFragmentManager()``` instead